# Listview empty after insert a field in db?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, listviewitem

I was looking for an example/tutorial to insert datas in a sqlLite db and display the datas in a listview. Well this is a good example: http://androidsolution4u.blogspot.it/2013/09/android-populate-listview-from-sqlite.html And it works. I implemented the code in mine and works. The problem is that if i want insert another one filed nothing appears in the listview and the activity is empty.I added a field called address as `string` like the others and in every part of code i added what is need copying from the others (of course changing the names). But when i try to add the item not appears. Of course i update the xml files with new field. I can't write the whole code because it's too much. But if someone can help me to find a way out i'll write the part of code required. Thanks
EDIT: the code is equal at the example but with the field i need to add.

The DisplayActivity

```
public class DisplayActivity extends Activity {

    private DbHelper mHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase dataBase;

    private ArrayList<String> userId = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> user_fName = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> user_lName = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> user_address = new ArrayList<String>();

    private ListView userList;
    private AlertDialog.Builder build;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display_activity);

        userList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.List);

        mHelper = new DbHelper(this);

        //add new record
        findViewById(R.id.btnAdd).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("update", false);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        //click to update data
        userList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("Fname", user_fName.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("Lname", user_lName.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("address", user_address.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("ID", userId.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("update", true);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        //long click to delete data
        userList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, final int arg2, long arg3) {

                build = new AlertDialog.Builder(DisplayActivity.this);
                build.setTitle("Delete " + user_fName.get(arg2) + " " + user_lName.get(arg2) + " " + user_address(arg2));
                build.setMessage("Do you want to delete ?");
                build.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),
                                        user_fName.get(arg2) + " "
                                                + user_lName.get(arg2)
                                                + user_address.get(arg2)
                                                + " is deleted.", 3000).show();

                                dataBase.delete(
                                        DbHelper.TABLE_NAME,
                                        DbHelper.KEY_ID + "="
                                                + userId.get(arg2), null);
                                displayData();
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                build.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = build.create();
                alert.show();

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        displayData();
        super.onResume();
    }

    /**
     * displays data from SQLite
     */
    private void displayData() {
        dataBase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor mCursor = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null);

        userId.clear();
        user_fName.clear();
        user_lName.clear();
        user_address.clear();
        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                userId.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_ID)));
                user_fName.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_FNAME)));
                user_lName.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_LNAME)));

            } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        DisplayAdapter disadpt = new DisplayAdapter(DisplayActivity.this,userId, user_fName, user_lName, user_address);
        userList.setAdapter(disadpt);
        mCursor.close();
    } 

}
```

The DisplayAdapter

```
public class DisplayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<String> id;
    private ArrayList<String> firstName;
    private ArrayList<String> lastName;
    private ArrayList<String> address;


    public DisplayAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> id,ArrayList<String> fname, ArrayList<String> lname, ArrayList<String> address) {
        this.mContext = c;

        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = fname;
        this.lastName = lname;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return id.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int pos, View child, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder mHolder;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        if (child == null) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            child = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listcell, null);
            mHolder = new Holder();
            mHolder.txt_id = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_id);
            mHolder.txt_fName = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_fName);
            mHolder.txt_lName = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_lName);
            mHolder.txt_address = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_address);
            child.setTag(mHolder);
        } else {
            mHolder = (Holder) child.getTag();
        }
        mHolder.txt_id.setText(id.get(pos));
        mHolder.txt_fName.setText(firstName.get(pos));
        mHolder.txt_lName.setText(lastName.get(pos));
        mHolder.txt_address.setText(address.get(pos));

        return child;
    }

    public class Holder {
        TextView txt_id;
        TextView txt_fName;
        TextView txt_lName;
        TextView txt_address;
    }

}
```

The DbHelper

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    static String DATABASE_NAME="userdata";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="user";
    public static final String KEY_FNAME="fname";
    public static final String KEY_LNAME="lname";
    public static final String KEY_ID="id";
    public static final String KEY_ADDRESS="address";
    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+KEY_FNAME+" TEXT, "+KEY_LNAME+" TEXT, "+KEY_ADDRESS+" TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }

}
```

And the AddActivity

```
public class AddActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
private Button btn_save;
private EditText edit_first,edit_last,edit_address;
private DbHelper mHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase dataBase;
private String id,fname,lname,address;
private boolean isUpdate;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_activity);

        btn_save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save_btn);
        edit_first=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.frst_editTxt);
        edit_last=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.last_editTxt);
        edit_address=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.address_editTxt);

       isUpdate=getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("update");
        if(isUpdate)
        {
            id=getIntent().getExtras().getString("ID");
            fname=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Fname");
            lname=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Lname");
            address=getIntent().getExtras().getString("address");
            edit_first.setText(fname);
            edit_last.setText(lname);
            edit_address.setText(address);

        }

         btn_save.setOnClickListener(this);

         mHelper=new DbHelper(this);

    }

    // saveButton click event 
    public void onClick(View v) {
        fname=edit_first.getText().toString().trim();
        lname=edit_last.getText().toString().trim();
        address=edit_address.getText().toString().trim();
        if(fname.length()>0 && lname.length()>0 && address.length()>0)
        {
            saveData();
        }
        else
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder=new AlertDialog.Builder(AddActivity.this);
            alertBuilder.setTitle("Invalid Data");
            alertBuilder.setMessage("Please, Enter valid data");
            alertBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                       dialog.cancel();

                }
            });
            alertBuilder.create().show();
        }

    }

    /**
     * save data into SQLite
     */
    private void saveData(){
        dataBase=mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();

        values.put(DbHelper.KEY_FNAME,fname);
        values.put(DbHelper.KEY_LNAME,lname );
        values.put(DbHelper.KEY_ADDRESS,address );

        System.out.println("");
        if(isUpdate)
        {    
            //update database with new data 
            dataBase.update(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, values, DbHelper.KEY_ID+"="+id, null);
        }
        else
        {
            //insert data into database
            dataBase.insert(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        }
        //close database
        dataBase.close();
        finish();


    }

}
```

That's all. I can't find the problem. Helps?

Comment: ok, i'm going to update the question with the code, just a minute

Comment: Any solution? Seems to be right the code.

Comment: what do you means exactly?

Comment: Could not see anything wrong yet. If you have not try this yet, try looking at the LogCat to see if there is any error message in there. Sometimes some error will be print out though your app will not crash. If you use eclipse try to clear the LogCat before your test.

Comment: Also, this "tutorial" is very suspicious to me. If you have a database and want to display its data, I see no reason not to use CursorAdapter at all. In this tutorial the guy actually read all data from SqlLite, save them into a bunch of list and then use a BaseAdapter to display them. Software engineering wise, there are too many things smelly about it. For example, If in your database is very large then your app might not work anymore. If you use CursorAdapter I believe it will still work.

Comment: thank you, i'll try to change something starting using a CursorAdapter instead a BaseAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

Forgotten in displayData() `user_address.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_ADDRESS)));`

Comment: Nothing appears again. Even if i add this line. I have only a blank activity.

Comment: Have you add any data to db after add field address?

Comment: yes i have. i think i've wrote everything right in code i posted. Right?

Comment: Can't see anything wrong. If it worked before add address, it must work now.

Comment: Anyway, I think it is better to use a CursorAdapter when using SQLite

Comment: What do you mean? Also that is another question. Create a new one.

Comment: sorry i've wrong the question. To much open sheet in chrome :) however, just for now, i need some help for this one if you can http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355914/how-create-edittext-with-sqllite-in-android-listview .